# Packet Capture and Retransmission, socat permission denied

Tags: raspberry-pi, packet-capture, socat

I am trying to do packet capture and retransmission using a raspberrypi using tcpdump and socat. However i keep getting the error:

tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
2023/09/26 20:17:17 socat[2400] E sendto(5, 0x3fb000, 24, 0, AF=2 192.168.7.255:14555, 16): Permission denied

Please help me out.

this sis the shell script
`#!/bin/bash

## Define the multicast group and port to capture

multicast_group="224.1.1.1"  # Replace with your specific multicast group address
multicast_port=12345  # Replace with the multicast port number

## Define the broadcast address and port to retransmit

broadcast_address="192.168.xxx.xxx"  # Broadcast address for the target network
forward_port=54321  # Replace with the port number you want to use for forwarding

while true; do

## Start tcpdump to capture UDP multicast packets

sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -n -s0 -U -w - "udp and port $multicast_port" | 
sudo socat -u - UDP4-DATAGRAM:$broadcast_address:$forward_port
done
`

I tried using sudo to make it executable but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

See man 5 socket:

> SO_BROADCAST
> Set or get the broadcast flag.  When enabled,  datagram  sockets
> are allowed to send packets to a broadcast address.  This option
> has no effect on stream-oriented sockets.

In Socat you set this flag with the so-broadcast option:

```
sudo socat -u - UDP4-DATAGRAM:$broadcast_address:$forward_port,so-broadcast
```